# Is there is something like code synonyms in C#?

Tags: c#

For example i have some code:

```
if (myArray[i, j, k] == someValue)
  myArray[i, j, k] = someOtherValue;
else
  throw new Exception(string.Format("value {0} is wrong!", myArray[i, j, k]));
```

and it seems that it is a bit dangerous. I would like to had some "code synonym", like that:

```
var xx => myArray[i, j, k];
if (xx == someValue)
  xx = someOtherValue;
else
  throw new Exception(string.Format("value {0} is wrong!", xx));
```

where `xx` isn't a value of `myArray[i, j, k]`, but a synonym to that code, and `=>` is some kind of declaration syntax for this construct.

I'd like to have this feature to ensure that multiply `myArray[i, j, k]` usage would be exactly the same code, without risk of getting `myArray[j, i, k]` in some place.

May be C# can do something like that, without ugly syntax? I mean safe code, not unsafe memory pointer. Or maybe something is wrong with my point of viewh?

---

I apologize for possibly incorrect definition of my idea. I'd like to use this trick ("code synonyms" or something like that) as regular feature of language(? or compiler etc), not only in this single case. Specialized classes or functions are good in particular case, but in general they will lead to a significant increase in the amount of code, and i would like to avoid this.

Comment: what is "dangerous" here? First version seems legit

Comment: "Dangerous" for the coder to accidentally mix up i, j and k.

Comment: You do this with a pointer.  Which certainly trumps "dangerous" any day.  `ArraySegment<T>` is a somewhat clumsy alternative.

Comment: Sten Petrov, Corak is right.

Comment: Well, in one way or another you *have* to use i, j and k at least twice in the right order. For getting and setting the value. You could put the value in a temporary variable and work with that between getting and setting.

Comment: Perhaps what you're wanting here is ref locals.  Which are actually supported by the CLR, but not by C#. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/23/ref-returns-and-ref-locals.aspx

Answer (score 4):

May be use some function for this? For example:

In your code:

```
UpdateElement(ref myArray[i, j, k], someValue, someOtherValue);
```

And function:

```
void UpdateElement(ref int element, int compareWith, int value)
{
     if (element == compareWith)
         element = value;
     else
         throw new Exception(string.Format("Value {0} is wrong!", element));
}
```

UPD: Method renaming from 'TryUpdateElement' to 'UpdateElement', because of Try.. methods usually don't throw exceptions.

Comment: Try... methods don't usually throw exceptions.

Comment: @alex, you are right. What's better naming? Just UpdateElement() ?

Comment: Yes, UpdateElement is better

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own matrix type that would store an actual index

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
    private T[, ,] _array;

    public Matrix(int sizeX, int sizeY, int sizeZ)
    {
        _array = new T[sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ];
    }

    public T this[int i, int j, int k]
    {
        get { return _array[i, j, k]; }
        set { _array[i, j, k] = value; }
    }

    public int CurrentI { get; set; }
    public int CurrentJ { get; set; }
    public int CurrentK { get; set; }

    public void SetCurrentCell(int i, int j, int k)
    {
        CurrentI = i;
        CurrentJ = j;
        CurrentK = k;
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get { return _array[CurrentI, CurrentJ, CurrentK]; }
        set { _array[CurrentI, CurrentJ, CurrentK] = value; }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Matrix<T> matrix)
    {
        return matrix.Current;
    }

    // The assignment operator (=) cannot be overloaded. But we can overload |
    // instead, allowing us to write: m |= value in order to perform an assignment.
    public static Matrix<T> operator |(Matrix<T> m, T value)
    {
        m.Current = value;
        return m;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var m = new Matrix<int>(3, 3, 3);
m[0, 2, 1] = 77;
m.SetCurrentCell(0, 2, 1);
m.Current = 88;
int value = m; // Using the implicit operator and the current indexes
m |= 20; // Using |= as assignment operator
```

---

The generic approach has the disadvantage that it becomes more difficult to implement numeric operations (mathematical operations like +, -, *, / are not defined on generic types). But you could resolve the generic type in a dervied class, that implements numeric calculations

```
public class DoubleMatrix : Matrix<double> {
    public static DoubleMatrix operator +(DoubleMatrix a, DoubleMatrix b)
    {
        //TODO: Implement + operator
        return m;
    }

    //TODO: Implement other operators
}
```

---

C# 7.0 introduced ref locals allowing you to do just that

```
ref int xx = ref myArray[i, j, k];
if (xx == someValue)
    xx = someOtherValue;
else
    throw new Exception(string.Format("value {0} is wrong!", xx));
```

Note that you get not only a synonym but a reference, which means that the array indexes get evaluated only once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is nice solution for case which I have described, especially with generics.

Comment: I replaced my example with a generic solution now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous delegates for this.

```
var get_xx = delegate(){ return myArray[i, j, k];};
var set_xx = delegate(int v){ myArray[i, j, k] = v;};

if (get_xx() == someValue)
  set_xx(someOtherValue);
else
  throw new Exception(string.Format("value {0} is wrong!", get_xx()));
```

Comment: The thing is, this will not (by _faaaar_) have the performance characteristics (far worse). Also note that it might not even do the same thing in the presence of limited scope names and/or value types.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As for me, this solution would be overkill for my case.

Comment: this is not just slower but uglier than directly accessing the array

Answer (score 0):

That last sentence is calling for obvious responses. It seems you'd like to use something like a code generator.

Something like a C preprocessor would appear to fit the bill:

```
#define xx myArray[i, j, k]
```

Well, that is indeed not the ... usual "point of view", but the good news is, you can simply use the CPP preprocessor in your C# project.

Ideas:

- Make it a prebuild step.
- generate your .cs from a .cs.cpp file

Comment: Wouldn't that break pretty much all C# tooling (IntelliSense, Resharper, …)?

Comment: @svick Not necessarily, to point out the obvious :) Even C# has the use of [`#line`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34dk387t(v=vs.71).aspx) directives to guide debuggers and source navigators. I've used this to great success with Parser Generators ("compiler compilers") like Coco/R (see my [contribution here](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/coco/CS/log.html)). (Note how I said this is really unusual - I'm just putting it out there)

Answer (score 0):

You could write yourself a function that allows you to do something like this:

```
UpdateMatrixValueIf(myArray, i, j, k, (v) => v == someValue, someOtherValue);
```

And implement it like this:

```
public void UpdateMatrixValueIf<T>(T[,,] array, int i, int j, int k, Func<T, bool> check, T newValue)
{
    if (check(array[i, j, k]))
        array[i, j, k] = newValue;
    else
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Value {0} is wrong!", array[i, j, k]));
}
```

Of course doing something like this only really makes sense, if you do it more than once. Otherwise the answer is simply no, that you can’t do it in a better or safer way. You could make use of some crazy reflection methods, but I don’t think that would be appropriate here. Just make sure such a code section is unit tested, and you shouldn’t end up with index issues.